# Dart Mockito: spies?

Tags: unit-testing, dart, spy

I don't see any mentions of spies support in Mockito for dart in the latest versions.

In the changelog:

> 2.0.0-dev #
>   Remove export of spy and any dart:mirrors based API from mockito.dart. Users may import as package:mockito/mirrors.dart going forward.
>   Deprecated mockito_no_mirrors.dart; replace with mockito.dart.
>   Require Dart SDK >=1.21.0 <2.0.0 to use generic methods.
>
> 0.11.1 #
>   Move the reflection-based spy code into a private source file. Now package:mockito/mockito.dart includes this reflection-based API, and a new package:mockito/mockito_no_mirrors.dart doesn't require mirrors.
>
> 0.10.0 #
>   Added support for spy.

Is there any support for spies in the context of unit-testing in Dart?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I cant believe they removed spy capability completely...